# how do i create a map with a type parameter of class

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import scala.swing

class componentMapper {

     val map = Map[Class[_], Componenet]()

     def apply(c: Class[_], component: Component) = map += (c -> componenet)

}

class Render extends ComponentMapper {

     def getRenderer(value: AnyRef) = map(value.getClass)

}
```

This doesn't seem to work. What type parameter should I be using for Class?

Comment: I've never used Scala, but I understand it runs on the JVM... isn't Map an interface and not a class?  Try HashMap instead.

Comment: Scala has builtin maps. The Map[...]() above is like a static factory method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the core problem is, but it's not the type parameter for class.  It appears to be some weird type inference issue with "->".  The following compiles and works just fine.

```
import scala.swing._

class ComponentMapper {
  var map = Map[Class[_], Component]()
  def apply(c: Class[_], component: Component) = map += ((c, component))
}

class Render extends ComponentMapper {
  def getRenderer(value: AnyRef) = map(value.getClass)
}
```

Note that I had to make many small corrections to your code to even find what problem you were talking about.

I've filed a ticket in case in hopes that it's something fixable: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1974.